# Why is adding -prune to this find command causing printing of extraneous files?

Tags: find

If I want to search the entire filesystem for a file with the name `bash`, I can run the command

```
% find / -name "bash" 2> /dev/null
```

which, on my system produces

```
/bin/bash
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/bash
/usr/share/doc/bash
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/usr/share/menu/bash
/rofs/bin/bash
/rofs/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/bash
/rofs/usr/share/doc/bash
/rofs/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/rofs/usr/share/menu/bash
```

Which is fine, but I know there are certain directories on the system where the file definitely is **not**, so to the make the search more efficient, I updated the command to:

```
% find / \ 
-name "proc" -prune -o \
-name "sys" -prune -o \
-name "run" -prune -o \
-name "bash" \
2> /dev/null
```

Now I am getting screenfuls of extraneous files, why is `find` doing this?

#### find version

```
% find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
```

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't specified a final action, `find` is treating this as if you'd done

```
find / \( -name .. -prune -o -name .... -o -name bash \) -print
```

The "-prune" returns true and so it prints out those directories.  That means every directory called `sys`, every directory called `proc` and so on.  Definitely a lot of directories if you have kernel source around!

eg

```
/sys
/var/run
/proc
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64/include/config/sys
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64/include/config/keys/debug/proc
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64/include/config/nf/conntrack/proc
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64/include/config/proc
```

All of those are called `sys` or `run` or `proc` or...

The simple answer is to add a `-print` to the end of your command

```
% find / -name "proc" -prune -o \
-name "sys" -prune -o \
-name "run" -prune -o \
-name "bash" -print \
2> /dev/null
```

Now `find` will only print `bash` entries

eg

```
/usr/share/doc/bash
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/usr/share/menu/bash
/bin/bash
```

Comment: thanks, so to summarize your first command, you could say that by default, the implicit `-print` action is always applied to all "primaries"?

Comment: If there's no action defined (other than `-prune`) then GNU find will implicitly add `-print` for you.  You had no action defined and so it took the whole expression as a single evaluation (effectively added the `\(...\)` around it) and then used the default `-print` action.

Comment: thanks, yes I already knew about the implicit `-print`, in fact I had already tried your suggestion of adding an explicit `print` to the primary I wanted to print . i.e.  `-name "bash" -print` . On my system that seems to make no difference, does it work for you on your system?

Comment: What I posted is an exact cut'n'paste of a real session.

Comment: Ah ok, I found what was happening - on my terminal I had (invisible) spaces after the `\\` at the end of each line. When I cleaned these up, I get the same result as you

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of the \ method of splitting lines; hidden spaces can cause problems!